# why my name server can not point to the right ip address?

Tags: dns, nameservers

I'm totally new about hosting website and I register a domain in network solution and hosted by hostgator. I tried to register my name server by going to Domain `name server option` in network solution and enter my name sever's name.However,by going to `leafdns.com`, I found out that the name servers don't pointing to the right ip addresses as provided by hostgator welcome email. Besides, network solution does not prompt you for a ip input for those name servers, and the domain still point to a construction page.
What would be the problem?

Comment: probably some faulty setting somewhere, or neglected to configure something, or incorrect method of testing the result. That's as accurate a guess as your problem description allows.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enaught to set up Name Servers for domain, you need add records in it. If you setup hostgator hosting NameServers for your domain, just park your domain on hosting panel and NS records add apear automatically.